# how to disable button using jQuery in yii

Tags: yii

i want to disable update button dan make it invisible using jQuery when update page is open, but if the value of payed is 1. i can get the value from database
somebody please help me, i'm a newbie in yii. thank you

Comment: Show us what you have tried at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your view file:

```
<?php  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
    'disable-button',
    '$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');',
    CClientScript::POS_READY
) ?>
```

But change jQuery selector on yours:

```
$('input[type="submit"]')
```